# Design for when a model can have three different types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

If I had a `Dog` model and you can choose it to be 1 out of 3 of the `Types` called Small, Medium and Large. Should these Types be models themselves if I'm going to put logic in them? What would be the model design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Small, Medium and Large will each have unique methods but share common attributes you could have a base Dog model and then subclass each of the sizes like `class SmallDog < Dog`. Use single table inheritance on the dogs table by adding a `type` column that accepts values like "SmallDog", etc.

Comment: What if I was aiming for them to be like 3 different categories and they can only have one. Would it be the same design?

Comment: They can only have one what? Sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: My bad, the Dog can only be one type ( small, medium or large) and this is treated like a category.

Comment: Right. By using single table inheritence and subclassing Dog it implicity sets the type attribute to whatever subclass you're dealing with. To illustrate, once STI and the subclasses are set up, go to rails console and type `SmallDog.new`. You'll see that the type attribute is automatically given the value "SmallDog".

Answer (score 2):

Will all the different types have a common interface but just differ in their logic?

If the interface is the same (i.e they all have the same function definitions) then I'd just have subclasses for each of the different types of dog that extend the original Dog model and have some kind of factory class that handles the creation of Dog models and automatically selects the appropriate class based on the type of Dog. By using the factory class with a common interface for Dog types the rest of the application does not need to care about the type of Dog and you can freely add/remove new types by simply modifying the factory class.